# letting jQuery load random src="" values, into various <img /> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, css-selectors

I want to load random built src values into 20 different img.

I'm getting a random number bewtween 1 and 20, and assign it to a name using switch.
The name is part of the src value, as well as the class value.

I am trying to acces the different img, by using `:nth-child()` and `i` as variable.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var i=1;
while (i<20){

    var n = getRandom(1, 20);
    name = getName(n);
    var class = $('#content div:nth-child('+i+')').attr('class');

    var src = 'img/preview/'+class+'/'+name+'.jpg';

    $('#content div:nth-child('+i+') img').attr('src', src);

    i++;
}
});
```

Maybe someone can give me a hint?

Comment: Can the images repeat? if you have twenty images and you want to show them all, you will have to keep track not to repeat.

Comment: yes, they can. But i want to fix that on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $images = $('#content img'); // Caching ffs !

for(var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    var name = getName(getRandom(1, 20));
    $images[i].attr('src', 'img/preview/' + $images[i].attr('class') + '/' + name + '.jpg');
}
```

"class" is a reserved word.